# Is there any negative social or psychological implication of the current “slime” preoccupation of teenagers (mostly girls)?

Tags: physiology, well-being, parenting, touch

This may not be the right place for this question.  If you think it belongs on another forum, please point me there.

My daughter has been into the “slime” craze for the past two years or so (she is now 14).  She makes several batches of slime a month.  She loves to play with slime.  She loves to watch YouTube videos of people playing with slime.  She sends pictures of her slime to her friends.  She wants me to touch her slime (I don’t like to because it is cold and slimy, ha, and it sticks to me, because she says I don’t know how to handle it).

I just started to wonder, the other day, why so many people, mostly young teen girls, are so infatuated with slime.  Is there some weird, psychological implication here?  Sexual, maybe?  Am I not touching her enough?  Or is it nothing?

Comment: It looks like the current version of the trend is [powered by cutsie colors](https://jezebel.com/the-girl-dominated-d-i-y-slime-trend-shows-no-signs-of-1795865479). Is that the case with your girl?

Comment: @Fizz, she does like to do a myriad of colors and textures.

Comment: How is slime different from other gender-specific fads over time? Are you asking for references to sociological publications about fads and their spread?